# Kafka Message Availability

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an application that uses an idempotent producer to write uniquely identifiable and orderable messages into a topic. When the application crashes and restarts, it checks the last message of every partition to determine which was the last succesful message it has written and then starts sending the next one.

To test the exactly-once writing semantics of this approach, I have containerized my entire set-up and at random intervals, I kill a single kafka broker container. At different random intervals, I kill my application. The killing of a broker and my application could therefore occur at the same time every now and then.

After killing, I quickly restart them and I have noticed that in some, relatively rare occassions, a message is written twice. I have identified the problem as **consumer.endOffsets() sometimes returning not the last offset of a partition but the one before that**. I suspect this may be because somehow the last message sent right before the application crashes is still in transit. I have also noticed that delaying the restart of my application solves this problem but this seems like a non-deterministic approach. I don't know exactly how long to wait before restarting...

I'd like to understand exactly where and how it is in transit and how I can make my application wait for this message to be guaranteed to be available either by sleeping in my application for a period of time that corresponds with some kafka configuration option, or some way to tell my consumer to wait for all messages in transit to be fully processed and available.

For reference, I have idempotence set to true, insync replicas to 2 and my topic has a replication factor of three. I have not manually specified retries nor acks so they are set automatically to infinite and all. There are no manual retries in my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't exactly know what details I can provide to help but don't hesitate to ask any if you need them.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but what is happening with your consumer end offset check exactly? It doesn't make sense that delaying restart would help here unless you are somehow capturing a scenario where replication hadn't completed so the message wasn't available for consumption yet. I'd expect the same result regardless of when you start the application again. Are you restarting faster than replication can happen so the high watermark can go up?

Comment: It's definitely possible that I am restarting faster than the replication can happen. The restarts are completely random so at times they can be within the second. Is there any way I can diagnose this? Maybe introduce some artificial delay in the replication somehow?

Comment: You could put an artificial delay in replication. On the brokers set replica.fetch.min.bytes to something large like 1mb and set replica.fetch.wait.max.ms to whatever delay you want and that should cause a bit more delay.

Comment: Another option is to delay restart a bit. Just kill and wait a second then start back up.